# Speeding up .js functions (specifically flipclock.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, flipclock

So here's the issue, I have a flipclock.js countdown on my page, but after watching it for 20-25 seconds, the clock either gets really slow, or stops completely. Some googling revealed that the creator mentioned it uses a high amount of cpu while running, is their anyway to reduce this? Should I minify/uglify my js?

What are my options here? I've seen flip clock run flawlessly on other sites but mine wants to lag and stop constantly.

For extra information, this is being built off of the hubspot cos/cms, but the clock will lag on a local hosted site as well?

Any help is appreciated!

Here is the [site](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3071475355&style_id=492504109&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=341117) in question.

HTML (module) of the clock:

```
<body>
  <div class="your-clock"></div>

  <script>
    var clock; 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Grab the current date 
    var currentDate = new Date(); 
    // Set some date in the future. ***change to desired date***
    //var futureDate = new Date(2015, 10, 23, 6, 0, 0); 
    var futureDate = new Date(2015, 09, 07, 11, 0, 0); //fixed as per comments
    // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date 
    var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000; 
    // Instantiate a coutdown FlipClock 
    clock = $('.your-clock').FlipClock(diff, { clockFace: 'DailyCounter', countdown: true }); 
    });
  </script>


</body>
```

Comment: minify/uglify wont solve poorly written or slow javascript - if the creator says it uses a lot of cpu, then nothing you can do about it except write it completely differently so that it doesn't use a lot of cpu

Comment: Hmm, would running something like velocity.js solve this? I just don't understand how some sites have it so smooth, did they completely rewrite theirs? I seemed to have misinterpreted how the creator mentioned the highcpu usage, here is the [post](https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/issues/74) in reference.

Comment: Not sure, throwing more javascript at slow javascript doesn't sound sane

Comment: Very true, just frustrated haha.. hmm I guess I can go through and try and chop whatever I'm not exactly using.

Comment: Even the original site eats my CPU, so I wouldn't use it in my project as of now, for sure...

Comment: The *amount* of javascript is rarely the problem, it is what it *does* that matters.

Comment: You could always try an alternative; a quick search brings up [this](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/) site which may suit your needs.

Comment: @ReinS unfortunately I would prefer to have the clock in green, but it doesn't seem like I'll be able to do that with countdown, guess I'll bite the bullet on that, countdown uses images as opposed js-created divs, so it should run a lot better.

Comment: @user4875251: According to the landing page, you can use the `color` and `bkgd` values of the `numbers` option to change the colors as you see fit. (edit: I guess these are only if you don't want the actual flip animation?)

Comment: @ReinS, I don't see how? The top one is supposedly running on a sprite image?